# differentiation formula steps for $10t^2 + 12$

Tags: calculus

I'm just starting self study calculus using the MIT open courseware.  I'm given velocity $v(t)=20t$ as the slope and am asked to find the distance formula when $f(0) = 12$.  I was able to do this using the area of a triangle formula $(\frac{1}{2})$(base)(height) and assuming interval $[0,T]$ where base $= T$ and height $= 20T$.  I got $10T^2$ and since $f(0) = 12$ I added $12$ to the formula for distance is $10t^2 + 12$.  All is good at this point.

I then tried to reverse this process by using the differentiation formula (not the rules) thinking I should be able to get back to where I stated.  I used the general formula for differentiation

$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$

So I plug in my specific formula $f(t) = 10t^2 + 12$ into this form over interval $[0,T]$ and get

$$\frac{10T^2 + 12 - (10(0) + 12)}{T - 0}$$

which becomes $\frac{10T^2}{T}$ and becomes $10T$.  But this does NOT match my original starting point of $v(t) = 20T$.  So can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: in this case, $f(x)=10x^2+12$ so $f(x+h)=10(x+h)^2+12=10x^2+20hx+10h^2+12$.  Subtracting $f(x)$ yields a numerator of $20hx+10h^2$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  Since f(x+h) would represent formula $10x^2 + 12$ when we put in our last input value of T then wouldn't $f(x + h) =  10T^2 + 12$.  Its clear you are getting the right answer but I guess I don't know why.  I'm trying to figure out how squaring of $(x+h)$ you are doing relates to T being my largest input value.  Like...shouldn't $x + h = T$

Comment: How could $f(x+h)=10T^2+12$?  The left hand is a function of $x$ and $h$, the right hand is a function of $T$.  For any $z$, $f(z)=10z^2+12$.  Thus $f(x+h)=10(x+h)^2+12$.

Comment: A derivative is a limit of the form $\frac 00$. The way you put it, neither the numerator nor the denominator approach zero.

Comment: nothing wrong with your formula. you calculated $f'(0)$ and got $f'(0)=0$ which is normal. but that's not how to calculate $f'(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yeah...I think I'm definitely messing up some basic algebra here.  So $\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ is the general form I was told to use to find the slope.  And am told that f(x + h) is the output of f with the largest input value and f(x) is the output of f with the smallest input value of 0.  Since my largest input is T and smallest input is $0$ I thought it would translate into $\frac{10T^2 + 12 -(10(0) + 12)}{T}$ but I'm clearly wrong because it doesn't work and therefor confused

Comment: The book hasn't gotten to limits yet.  I'm just trying to reverse the first process I did.

Comment: @zwim.  So I'm using to wrong formula to reverse this process?  Can you provide the correct one I should be using?  I also saw on youtube using this same formula but its not working for me.

Comment: You correctly calculated the area of the triangle, but you cannot simply _add $12$_; rather, you have to add $12t$ since the area of the rectangle [below the triangle] varies over time.